# How to get function names of an object in Javascript on Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat, ecmascript-3

I'm trying to get function names of an object inside a webview on Android 4.4 (EcmaScript 3), with no luck.

`Object.keys` doesn't work, `for (var x in obj)` doesn't work.

Printing content of the object itself returns `{}` as well as printing `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

I do know that the object contains an `open` method, so evaluating `obj["open"]` results in `function open() { [native code] }`.

Also, the `obj` object is a JavascriptInterface object (that's why it's native code).

Any thoughts?